# gdb macro to determine the architecture of debugged program

Tags: gdb

I need to write some gdb macros that need to different between 32 and 64 bit architectures.
I'm looking for a way to determine in gdb whether the debugged executable is 32 or 64 bit.

info target includes info about file type

e.g.  file type elf32-i386

but this is embedded in a longer output.

Being new to gdb macros, I don't know how to process that output, or find another way to get this.

Please, no python gdb for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

**Python API example**

```
frame = gdb.selected_frame()
arch = frame.architecture()
print(arch.name())
```

Sample outputs:

- `i386` for a 32 bit ELF
- `i386:x86-64` for a 64 bit ELF

Docs: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Architectures-In-Python.html

Tested on GDB 7.7.1, Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution, not 'contaminated' with python:

```
define set-program-arch
    set logging file tmp.gdb
    set logging overwrite on
    set logging redirect on
    set logging on
    set pagination off
    info target
    set pagination on
    set logging off
    set logging redirect off
    set logging overwrite off
    shell echo -n 'set $program_arch="' > tmp2.gdb
    shell grep 'file type' tmp.gdb | sed "s/\.$//g" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | tr -d '\n' >> tmp2.gdb
    shell echo '"' >> tmp2.gdb
    source tmp2.gdb
    shell rm -f tmp2.tmp tmp.gdb
end
```

This sets variable **program_arch** to ELF type of the binary being debugged (e.g. **elf64-x86-64**). Enjoy!

Comment: Very nice, thanks. It also answers the general question of how to process gdb output.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found an extremely simple answer:

```
if sizeof(uintptr_t) == 4
  set $arch = 32
else 
  set $arch = 64
end
```

Comment: You've found the answer to a different question from the one you asked. Good luck using this method distinguishing between elf32-i386 and elf32-ppc.

Comment: Isn't `unitptr_t` a typo?  Shouldn't that be `uint` not `unit`?  Also, why do you use `sizeof(uintptr_t)` instead of `sizeof(void *)` or even `sizeof(unsigned int *)`?  The latter might work better for C, C++, and Objective-C, not just C++11 and C99 with `<stdint.h>` included.

Answer (score 0):

> Please, no python gdb for the time being.

I don't believe you can achieve what you want without python-gdb, and it is *trivial* to achieve what you want with it. So consider relaxing your restriction.

Comment: Well, how about an example in python?